# Why my starting Activity is not working?

Tags: java, android

First I want to say is that I am new to Android. I want to start my `Activity` from an `AsyncTask`, but I don't know why I am getting an error.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String string) {
    // Now we have your JSONObject, play around with it.

    //MainActivity.t.setText(string);

    MainActivity.mainActivity.startPlataform();
}
```

This is my `onPostExecute()` when everything works and I am accessing from a static `MainActivity` variable, but I don't know another way to do it.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public static MainActivity mainActivity;
    public Intent detailIntent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mainActivity = new MainActivity();
        detailIntent = new Intent(this, Main_Plataform.class);
    }

    ...

    public void startPlataform() {
        try {
            startActivity(detailIntent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Fehler!", "Error why ???" + e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

When I call the `startPlataform()` method with a `Button` in my `MainActivity` it works fine 
but it does not in `the onPostExecute(). I think something about the static variable is wrong.

Here is my logcat:

```
05-03 20:41:37.403: E/AndroidRuntime(1562): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-03 20:41:37.403: E/AndroidRuntime(1562): Process: com.example.patronusgps, PID: 1562
05-03 20:41:37.403: E/AndroidRuntime(1562): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-03 20:41:37.403: E/AndroidRuntime(1562):     at
android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3424)
05-03 20:41:37.403: E/AndroidRuntime(1562):     at
android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3385)    
05-03 20:41:37.403: E/AndroidRuntime(1562):     at
android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3627)    
05-03 20:41:37.403: E/AndroidRuntime(1562):     at
android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3595)
05-03 20:41:37.403: E/AndroidRuntime(1562):     at
com.example.patronusgps.MainActivity.startPlataform(MainActivity.java:72)
05-03 20:41:37.403: E/AndroidRuntime(1562):     at
com.example.patronusgps.JSONParser.onPostExecute(JSONParser.java:106)
05-03 20:41:37.403: E/AndroidRuntime(1562):     at
com.example.patronusgps.JSONParser.onPostExecute(JSONParser.java:1)
05-03 20:41:37.403: E/AndroidRuntime(1562):     at
android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
05-03 20:41:37.403: E/AndroidRuntime(1562):     at
android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
05-03 20:41:37.403: E/AndroidRuntime(1562):     at
android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
05-03 20:41:37.403: E/AndroidRuntime(1562):     at
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-03 20:41:37.403: E/AndroidRuntime(1562):     at
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-03 20:41:37.403: E/AndroidRuntime(1562):     at
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
05-03 20:41:37.403: E/AndroidRuntime(1562):     at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-03 20:41:37.403: E/AndroidRuntime(1562):     at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-03 20:41:37.403: E/AndroidRuntime(1562):     at
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
05-03 20:41:37.403: E/AndroidRuntime(1562):     at
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
05-03 20:41:37.403: E/AndroidRuntime(1562):     at
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: just a side thing, please format your code better with better intents to make it more readable,

Comment: What do you want to do here: `MainActivity.mainActivity.startPlataform();` or here: `mainActivity = new MainActivity();`? Instantiating an `Activity` like this is something you should NEVER do. Use an `Intent` to start a new `Activity`.

Comment: Ok, i was just traying to get the context from there, but know i feel stupid xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First remove everything like this:

```
public static MainActivity mainActivity;
```

or this:

```
mainActivity = new MainActivity();
```

Both of those things are completely wrong. You should never insatiate an `Activity` like this and never hold a reference to an `Activity` in a static variable. This will only cause problems and mess up your app.

You can also remove the definition of `detailIntent` from your `MainActivity`:

```
public Intent detailIntent;
```

And remove its declartion from the `onCreate()` method:

```
detailIntent = new Intent(this, Main_Plataform.class);
```

You don't need all of that. If you want to start an `Activity` create a new `Intent` everytime.

Everytime you want to start any `Activity` regardless of where in your code you want to do it, you can do it basically like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, <Activity you want to start>.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

You need to pass the `Context` of your `Activity` to your `AsyncTask` to start the Activity from there, in this example I start the `MainActivity`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Ok uderstood, but how do i Pass the context. Like this ?           MainActivity.this.context or , MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext()

Comment: Doesn't matter which `Context` you use. But beware of memory leaks. Use `WeakReferences`.

Comment: Thanks everything went better, hopefully i will be clever as you someday